# Postgresql execute dynamic query inside function return NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I've a Postgresql function that will get some input (query value from these parameters by a dynamic query) and return the value (in here it is unique so the result should be an integer).

However, I can query the dynamic normally (it is easy just select value from table where id = 'abcd') by terminal and get value (for example: 2). But when I  execute the function, the value of Executed dynamic query always return NULL.

How can I solve this? It is tired when I could not know why EXECUTE "query" INTO variable but variable return NULL while "query" can return value when run in another terminal.

Here is my function, and I want return _result_value (it always NULL - NOTICE:  RESULT ABC: ). when I can query by psql.

```
SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity WHERE id = 15
 uom_id 
--------
      1
(1 row)




   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_field(
    selected_table text,
    selected_field text,
    field_type_sample anyelement,
    where_clause text DEFAULT ''::text)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    -- Log
    ME  constant text := 'selected_field()';
    -- Local variables
        _qry          text;
        _result_value ALIAS FOR $0;
    abc integer := 0;
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'FUNCTION select_field';
       --- _qry := 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(selected_field) ||
       ---          ' FROM ' || quote_ident(selected_table) ||
       ---               ' ' || where_clause;

    _qry := ' SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity WHERE id = 15; ';

    RAISE NOTICE 'WHAT IN HERE: query %', _qry;

       -- return 1000;              
       -- RAISE DEBUG '%: %', ME, _qry;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Preparing to query data';
       -- EXECUTE _qry INTO  _result_value; 
        --EXECUTE (' SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity WHERE id = ''15'' ') into abc;
    EXECUTE ' SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity WHERE id = 15; ' into _result_value;
    RAISE NOTICE 'RESULT ABC: %', _result_value;



        RETURN  _result_value;
    END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working on my database. Maybe you are executing different instance of this function - PostgreSQL allows function overloading, and some mysterious bugs are based on more functions with same name.

I am pretty dislike this kind of functions - you try to hide SQL - and the usual result if this technique is pretty slow applications, but it is your life :). With modern PostgreSQL you can write your function little bit more readable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_field text, _table text, _id int,
                               resulttypedval anyelement, OUT _result anyelement)
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM %I'
                      ' WHERE $1 IS NULL OR id = $1',
                  _field, _table)
     INTO _result
     USING _id;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try as you require.